# How to change file extension when saving selected file in a FileUpload to the server

Tags: c#, winforms, file-upload

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/ProcessedFiles/" + fileName));
```

The file am grabbing from FileUpload1 to save on the server is a .xls file (Excel 97-2003)

What i want is to save it with a .xlsx extension (Excel 2007 and above) on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Path.ChangeExtension`

```
string path = "C:\\SomePath\\Somefile.xls";
string newPath = Path.ChangeExtension(path, ".xlsx");
```

In your case, probably something like this (not tested):

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
fileName = Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/ProcessedFiles/", fileName));
FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Path.ChangeExtension(fileName, ".xlsx"));
```

Comment: this saves the file in the 2007 ++ (.xlsx) format BUT corrupts the file. The saved file can neither be read programmatically in c# nor can it be opened from windows explorer. How can i avoid this file corruption?

Comment: Well that's another problem altogether. You can't do that easily because xls uses the old Excel PIA and the xlsx uses ooxml. So you'd have to either reference both the PIA assembly and the OpenXML assembly (and create your own logic for converting) or find some 3rd party solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the Filename without its original extension, and then append a new extension to it by using [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(String path)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx), like so:

```
String filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName) + ".xlsx";
FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/ProcessedFiles/" + filename));
```

On second thought, I totally forgot about `ChangeExtension()`, as @Matt has suggested. You should use his code.

Comment: If i use this method and try opening the file, i get Error Excel cannot open the file, 'FileNameHere' because the file format or file extension is not valid.

Comment: This is not an error in this code, it has something to do with the fact that you are trying to open an `xls` file with an `xlsx` extension. The code above does what it states; it changes the extension. For a better alternative to changing a file extension please use @Matt's code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx) method instead of `Path.GetFileName`

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName) + "xlsx";
FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/ProcessedFiles/" + fileName));
```